# Master view not updating with delegate from detail view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update the Master view in a `UISplitView` when a user taps a `UIBarButtonItem` in the detail view, which represents a favourite button. For some reason, the delegate method never gets called. Relevant code below. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

protocol FavouriteCaseDelegate: class {
func updateMasterForFavouriteStatusChange(caseID: Int, favouriteStatus: Bool)
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

weak var favouriteDelegate: FavouriteCaseDelegate? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Configure favourite bar button
    favouriteButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    if caseFavourited == false {
        favouriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FavouriteIcon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    } else {
        favouriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FavouriteIconSelected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    favouriteButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(didTapFavouriteBarButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    favouriteButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let favouriteBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: favouriteButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favouriteBarButton
}

func didTapFavouriteBarButton() {
    caseFavourited = !caseFavourited

    CaseManager.caseWorker.changeFavouritedStateForCase(subjectID: subjectID, caseID: caseID, isFavourited: caseFavourited)

    favouriteDelegate?.updateMasterForFavouriteStatusChange(caseID: caseID, favouriteStatus: caseFavourited)
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, FavouriteCaseDelegate {

func updateMasterForFavouriteStatusChange(caseID: Int, favouriteStatus: Bool) {
    print("updateMasterForFavourite called")
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: did you set the `detailviewcontroller.delegete = self` in mastertableviewcontroller?

Comment: Try to set  masterViewController as delegate at the time when you are instantiating or performing segue to detail view controller.

Comment: Aha - that's done it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `MasterTableViewController` class you need to set  `DetailViewController-> favouriteDelegate to self` for instance:-

```
//Assuming you have reference of detailViewController inside your MasterTableViewController class
let detailViewController =  DetailViewController()
detailViewController.favouriteDelegate = self
```

> Once set the delegate and invoke the method then it should called.

Comment: I've added that now but unfortunately the method still isn't getting called.

Comment: Where did you add?

Comment: viewDidLoad of the Master view

Comment: what value you are getting when you print favouriteDelegate inside updateMasterForFavouriteStatusChange??

Comment: Well, I'm not sure because the method never gets called. The remaining code in didTapFavouriteBarButton() runs but just not the delegate method.

Comment: You can put the print statement there and check. Seems like it is nil

Comment: Yup, if I add the print statement to didTapFavouriteBarButton(), it is indeed nil

Comment: Cool, So you found the issue